# How to run try, break or continue in python for function loop?

Tags: python, function, try-catch

I have two function calls which are presented below.

```
stlsplit(mesh, Direction, FeatureAngle)
num_lines, result = surface_check()
```

The second function is run from the output of the first function. The second function gives output as num_lines (Integer) and result (string, say "success' or "failure").

Now I need to put a condition where I need to satisfy num_lines > 500000 & result = "Success".
This will be obtained only when the first function (stlsplit) is kept on running for different variables of FeatureAngle. How to do this using **try or any other conditions**?

This might be a low question. But leads will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you planning to run the second function on the output of the first if you don't assign output of the first function to anything?

Comment: Why not just use `if-else`, i.e. `if num_lines > 50000 and result=='Success': do something`

Comment: @pavel The output of the first function contains files which are saved in the directory. Using these files, the second function is run.

What I mean to say is:

`If num_lines < 500000 and result "Success":
  run "first_function with different variable"
num_lines, result = surface_check()`

If the above code doesnt satisfy again, I need to write another "if loop" for first function with different variable.

Understood?

Comment: @pavel
Should be something like this:
`if num_lines < 500000 or result == "failure":
    try:
        for i in range(10, 20):
            stlsplit(mesh, Direction, i)
            num_lines, result = surface_check()
            break
    except:
        pass`

This is not exactly correct. Meaning the functions should run until num_lines > 500000 and result = "success"

Comment: I recommend adding pseudocode to your post (what steps need to be taken when). Not in the comments, but in the main body.  The logic is not very clear right now.

Comment: Also, `try` is for catching exceptions.  If you want your loop to run continuously until some condition is met, use a `while True` loop and a `break` statement inside the loop to break out of the loop when the condition you specify is satisfied.